# Howto configure P2P search engine YaCy for LAN and WWW

Tags: search-engine, p2p, decentralized-applications

YaCy is a free distributed search engine, built on principles of peer-to-peer (P2P) networks ["wikipedia YaCy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YaCy).

After installation, you can use it to search the WWW, but not your own computer.

However, I have found a guide that shows how to configure it for the LAN (["set up YaCy on LAN without public network"](https://translate.google.de/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yacy-websuche.de%2Fwiki%2Findex.php%2FDe%3AFirmenLAN%23eine_YaCy-Maschine_im_LAN)).

So I hope it might be configurable so it can be used for both.

Maybe you have a idear?
I would like to use it in Linux Lubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5y5MmnmraA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUAylWYqzac

First of all, Check **Use Cases** and **Network**, configure it as you need. Share URLs white indexing (crawling), accept remote ones or not.

After that you *need* to crawl pages you want to search. You can schedule your crawl to re crawl after period of time.

After those 2 steps you can search local http/https/ftp content, which you crawled.

Comment: Can you explain the content of the youtube links?